# Is there a nice formula for multiplicative inverses $\pmod n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was looking over Abstract Algebra by Gallian and I noticed the following problem (my wording):

> Consider the group $Z_n = \langle x \rangle$, let $a$ be relatively prime to $n$, and let $f$ be an automorphism such that $f(x^a) = x^b$. Find a formula for $f(x^c)$ for any $c$.

Of course, we want an $m$ such that $(x^a)^m= x^c$, so we want $am \equiv c \pmod n$, and thus $m \equiv a^{-1}c \pmod n$. Now with such an $m$, we have that $f(x^c) = x^{bm}$. However, is there an explicit formula for $a^{-1}$, or does the final answer have to be "$f(x^c) = x^{a^{-1}m}$, where $a^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $a$ in $\pmod n$?"

Comment: Sure, there is a explicit formula: $a^{-1}=a^{\phi(n)-1}$. Indeed, this formula can be used to effectively compute the inverses.

Comment: @W-t-P Oh of course, thanks!